# Displaying a route between two points in google maps on android

Tags: android, google-maps, location, routes

Two questions:

NOTE: I am not implementing google maps in my application, I am passing google maps (the installed application) arguments

First: How do I find my current location in google maps?

Second: How would I tell google maps to display a route between two points.

Currently I use an activity to tell google maps to create two or more geopoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find your current location using the system `LocationManager`. There's more information [in the developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

For the second part, this isn't something that you'll be able to do without using the Google Maps libraries. There's no existing intent or registered URI for the Google Maps application that will draw directions between two points. Sorry!